Rasmussen Equation 5.9
Can any one add the steps showing how Rasmussen (Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, the MIT Press, 2006) got from line 1 to line 2 of equation 5.9. (pg 114)? It is calculating the gradient of the log-likelihood.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d\theta_j} \log p(y|X, \theta) &= \frac{1}{2}y^T K^{-1}\frac{dK}{d\theta_j}K^{-1}y - \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(K^{-1}\frac{dK}{d\theta_j})\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\Bigl((\alpha\alpha^T-K^{-1})\frac{dK}{d\theta_j}\Bigl)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Where: $\alpha=K^{-1}y$ and $K$ is PSD

It is due to the cyclic property of the trace:
$$\mathrm{tr}ABC = \mathrm{tr}BCA = \mathrm{tr}CAB$$
Substituting $A = \alpha^T$, $B = dK/d\theta_j$, and $C = \alpha$, and performing the rotation above (from $ABC$ to $CAB$) gives us:
$$\alpha^T{dK\over d\theta_j}\alpha = \mathrm{tr}\left(\alpha^T{dK\over d\theta_j}\alpha\right) = \mathrm{tr}\left(\alpha \alpha^T{dK \over d\theta_j}\right)$$
where the first equality is due to the fact that $\alpha^T{dK\over d\theta_j}\alpha$ is a scalar, hence equal to its own trace.
We can get the rest of the way there by using the additive properties of the trace:
$$\mathrm{tr}A + \mathrm{tr}B =\mathrm{tr}(A+B)$$
